# Typesetting error margins in SI units

Tags: siunitx

I want to write the following:

18 ± 1 nm  (that's a plus/minus sign)

I'm using the `siunitx` package but in their manual I can't see anything about adding errors to the numbers of units. I've tried `\SI{18 \pm 1}{\nano\metre}` but that outputs "18(1) nm" which isn't the format I want.

Comment: `\SI[separate-uncertainty]{18\pm 1}{\nano\meter}`

Comment: This is shown on page `28` of  the manual and can be easily found ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I was searching for "error" rather than "uncertainty"